# "Уведомляем Вас" или "Уведомляю Вас"?

Tags: выбор-слов, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно: "Уведомляем Вас" или "Уведомляю Вас", если письмо подписывает руководитель предприятия?

Answer (score 2):

Возможны оба варианта. Он может уведомлять как от своего имени, так и от имени всего предприятия.